# Is there a quick way to obtain a perfect Yveltal?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So far Yveltal is probably my favorite legendary, I'm attempting to legitimately catch one with IVs I prefer.

I have a theory, please help me validate it, that using Nintendo's app that transfers save data to the SD/microSD card I save before my encounter with Yveltal, and copy my data on to another SD card(I know this part works from experience) as a back-up, then I use one the save data from one card and catch, and transfer Yveltal over to AS to quickly check the IVs, if fail overwrite the save(because of the annoying auto-save) with the back up and continue.

I realize that this would be a major exploit because of the obvious duplication, which is why I'm afraid of testing it myself, and I am not intending to duplicate.  I'm sure there's a much better, shorter, and sweeter way to go about this without saving that I'm not thinking of, if you have one such method it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm assuming you already know about the Synchronise ability and how it affects natures.

A faster way to determine the IVs is simply to save your game before the encounter, catch Yveltal, keep it in your party, and then during the battle with Lysandre, check its stats with the summary screen. Put these stats into an [IV checker](http://www.metalkid.info/pokemon/calculators/iv.aspx) and it will put out the possible IVs it can have! Then, if the IVs are bad, simply soft reset and try again!

There are ways to speed this up even more, avoiding even the catching step if the yveltal is bad. First, set up your party to look like this:

1. Your synchroniser at the front of the party, fainted (the synchronise effect will still work!)
2. A pokemon that knows Final Gambit, with one HP less than the maximum Yveltal would have with 31 IVs in HP. Make sure it outspeeds Yveltal - give it a Choice Scarf if you have one.
3. A pokemon that knows a status move such as Thunder Wave with one speed less than Yveltal would have with the nature you want and 31 IVs in Speed. (Make sure it doesn't have Iron Barbs, Rough Skin, Flame Body, or Poison Point, as you don't want yveltal to accidentally get burnt, poisoned, or take extra damage)
4. Any pokemon
5. Any pokemon
6. An empty slot to avoid the "do you want to keep yveltal or send it to your PC?" question after you catch it

Here is what you do when you encounter the Yveltal:

1. Use Final Gambit. If yveltal survives, it has a perfect HP IV, continue to step 2. If it faints, it is not perfect so you should immediately soft-reset.
2. Send out your pokemon in slot #3 above.
3. Use your status move. If Yveltal outspeeds, it either has a perfect speed IV or it won a speed tie with a slightly-imperfect speed IV, so continue to step 4. If your pokemon goes first, immediately soft-reset.
4. Catch Yveltal and continue to battle with Lysandre.
5. Check Yveltal's stats and see what its other IVs are.

I used this method when soft-resetting to catch perfect legendaries in ORAS, and it helped speed things up a lot!

Comment: Wow, that's an impressive and clever preparation! Out of curiosity, how much time does it take you in average to catch your perfect legendaries through this method? Since there is theoretically about one out of 29 000 000 legendary with 5 perfect IVs - do you accept less than 31 IVs in (Special) Attack and (Special) Defence?

Comment: @Ananas - In gen 6, all legendaries are guaranteed to have at least 3 perfect IVs, which helps a lot. Otherwise it varies depending on how lucky you are -- I caught a perfect terrakion after about 4 hours but it took me 8+ for an almost-perfect suicune. I recommend watching TV or doing something else mindless while SRing for legendaries.

Comment: So there's about one legendary out of 3000 with 5 perfect IVs and desired nature. Sounds more reasonable in that case! And thanks to your method we can avoid to try catching more than half of them.

Comment: I've heard of this method, I just don't have the pokemon with stats as of yet, I'm raising some currently.  I believe I could live without Physical Attack as I'm wanting a Special Attack maybe with Foul Play, not sure yet still working on the move set, but either Lonely for Attack or Mild for Special Attack. Do you think this process will be faster if I defeated Yveltal the first time and come back later for the recapture?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot you can't rebattle in XY like other games.

Comment: @BreakinDragon: It depends what you want to do with it. Rash is good for offensive sets (yveltal's sucker punch is the strongest priority move in the game, so it would be a waste to pass it up), and bold and impish are good for defensive sets. Otherwise if you don't care about sucker punch, modest or timid would be your best bets, as yveltal has a pretty large special movepool.

Comment: What it takes to be a master